# Add border to the user picture in AltaCV

Tags: altacv

Considering the AltaCV template:

https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV/blob/master/sample.tex

Do you know a way to add a border to the photo?

Comment: Without a working example, I can't be sure, but a patch of the `\@makeaphoto` macro (defined at line 228 of `altacv.cls`) should be the right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I edited the makephoto macro:

```
\newcommand{\@makeaphoto}[2]{%
  \begin{minipage}{#1}%
    \if@normalphoto
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}}
    \else
      \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={#2}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];
    \fi%
  \end{minipage}%
}
```